# How to fix error "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: javascript, c#, fetch-api

I have written an API and deployed to the server, I am using JS to call the API and send data to the database and I am getting the error:

> "415 Unsupported Media Type"

I tried putting it back to JSON format but it almost doesn't work, can anyone help me fix this?
Here is the code I use:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#form");

    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const payload = new FormData(form);

        console.log([...payload]);

        fetch('http://20.231.38.177:8000/api/products', {
            mode: "no-cors",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            charset: "utf-8",
            },
            body: payload,
        })
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data =>console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to add item.', error));
    });
```

Comment: Your Accept is "application/json" but your payload is FormData, that looks like a mismatch.